# how to prepend a file using the data from another file without creating new file in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, file, prepend

I tried to prepend a file using data from another file. But unfortunately I cant find a way to prepend the existing file by using the data from another file, so now I'm creating a 3rd file(test) by appending data from both files in the correct order as below:

```
import os
if os.path.exists("test3.csv"):
    os.remove("test3.csv")

with open("test.csv") as f1:
    with open("test 2.csv") as f2:
        with open("test3.csv","a") as f3:
            for line in f2:
                f3.write(line)
                for line in f1:
                    f3.write(line)
```

Is it possible to achieve the same without the creation of a new file?

Comment: Prepending a file means overwriting the data in the original file. You cannot do this unless you either create another file or read the data from the original file into RAM. Also, the last two lines should be unindented by one level.

Comment: Thanks @DYZ! Will stick with new file creation..